# Unable connect DNN6 to SQL Server 2012 developer edition

Tags: dotnetnuke, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Server 2012 Developer edition installed.

When I want to connect to SQL Server from Visual Studio 2010 I have only option to connect to `VISTAUSER-PC/SQLEXPRESS` but I know that the name of 2012 Developer edition is `VISTAUSER-PC` so I just write that name, test connection and its working.

DotNetNuke just gives me option to connect to express edition and when I enter `VISTAUSER-PC` for the name of the server it cannot connect. I know that DNN works with SQL Server 2012

http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/7582/captureqnn.jpg

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have a database called database.mdf. Did you mean to use the first option? You should make sure user instances are enabled on your 2012 instance. Also note that user instances are deprecated.

Comment: First option is for express edition  and when I use that option it gives me ./SQLEXPRESS instance and database named Database.mdf and it works but I want to use MS Server 2012.

Comment: I can connect To vistuser-pc from Visual Studio no problem

Comment: I think the options are misnomers. They should be called "User Instance" and "Normal Database"

Comment: Your database instance is probably running fine, but you don't have a database called database.mdf. You should create a database called DotNetNuke or something to that effect.

Comment: ok i will create database manually but will DNN still give me connection error?

Comment: Gonna have to try and find out...

Answer (score 0):

If your DotNetNuke install is on the same box as IIS/SQL2012/VS2012 then you just select "SQL Server 2005/2008 (Express) File".
You need to make sure other SQL instances, except SQL 2012, are NOT running on your machine when you do this....

DotNetNuke ships with a database.mdf file which is used by default by SQLExpress.

To recap.. 
Do not edit your SQL connection strings in your web.config
Stop any other SQL instance but SQL2012
Select the radio button beside "SQL Server 2005/2008 (Express) File".

I have noticed that SQL2012 uses a different account to run under so you may need to go in and change to "Network Service" so you can cleanly connect to SQL20102

Good luck...